# Windows 7 64-bit machine Blue Screen every time it wakes up from sleep

Tags: windows-7, bsod, sleep

Any idea how to fix it?

Computer is a Gateway FX6802.
Intel Core i7 940 @ 2.93GHz
12.0 GB Ram
64-bit Windows 7 OS

I got a new monitor to replace one of the monitor's in my 2-monitor setup. But I don't see how that would cause such a problem.

Also, although this BSOD (blue screen of death) problem is new, I've had a problem for years where the computer will suddenly freeze solid, requiring hard reboot. It often happens very soon after coming out of sleep, but also at other times. I don't know if the two problems are related at all.

I keep getting this error message on the blue screen every morning for the last several days, but the stop code changes slightly in the third section in parentheses (a previous time, it was `0xFFFFFA800C8DCE30`):

```
INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR

Technical information:
*** STOP: 0x000000A0 (0x0000000000000001,0x0000000000000006,0xFFFFFA800C8DCE30,0
x0000000000000000)
```

Windows Event Viewer says:

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power 
   [ Guid]  {331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4} 

   EventID 41 

   Version 2 

   Level 1 

   Task 63 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x8000000000000002 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2013-09-06T18:19:28.540024600Z 

   EventRecordID 827962 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  4 
   [ ThreadID]  8 

   Channel System 

   Computer FXPC 

  - Security 

   [ UserID]  S-1-5-18 


- EventData 

  BugcheckCode 160 
  BugcheckParameter1 0x1 
  BugcheckParameter2 0x6 
  BugcheckParameter3 0xfffffa800cb112c0 
  BugcheckParameter4 0x0 
  SleepInProgress true 
  PowerButtonTimestamp 0
```

Another crash on 12/21/2013. I didn't see an actual BlueScreen, everything just froze. Hard reboot required. It happened about 5-10 minutes after starting up the computer from the off position (not sleep/hibernation).

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   117
  BCP1: FFFFFA800A143010
  BCP2: FFFFF880059DCE30
  BCP3: 0000000000000000
  BCP4: 0000000000000000
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  768_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\122113-24944-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-178433-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: upload the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump, I need to look at them with Windbg

Comment: Hi @magicandre1981 I would love to upload it for you to look at. Is it possible to upload files to superuser? I'm looking for a file upload tool but don't see it. Perhaps I can upload it somewhere else and have you examine it.

Comment: zip tje dmp fiels and uplaod the zip to Skydrive/dropbox or a FREE 1 click hoster like zippyshare.com/mediafire.com

Comment: Hi @magicandre1981 I created a zip file on skydrive with 3 dump files inside of it. http://sdrv.ms/1dWE4hD

Comment: the dumps are not helpful. Increase the size of the hibernation file with powercfg. Also update some old drivers like e1y62x64.sys (Intel nIC driver).

Comment: @magicandre1981 http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/?iid=subhdr+dnlds_detect only detected one out-of-date driver for the network controller. I will see if I can get you bigger dump files. But note, it's not hibernation, it's sleep. maybe they are the same thing now, I don't know.

Comment: since vista, windows uses hybrid sleep (also writes a hibernation file)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's a hardware issue. You should probably call your computer manufacture. If you want to troubleshot it yourself you could try using system restore to undo recent software changes. [This](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Resolving-stop-blue-screen-errors-in-Windows-7) article might help you troubleshoot.

Comment: My system restore does not work. No restore points have been made/saved for years, even though the setting is turned on.